# Tensorrt python API set batch size

Tags: nvidia, tensorrt, tensorrt-python

I want to set the batch size when building a TensorRT engine.

I am using TensorRT 7 and the python API. I am converting a ResNet50 Model in onnx format.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it in the python API. However, I have used the `trtexec` tool that comes by default with tensorrt. The tool converts onnx models to tensorrt engines.

To convert a model use the following command:

```
trtexec --explicitBatch --onnx=model.onnx --minShapes=input:min_batchxsample_size --maxShapes=input:max_batchxsample_size --optShapes=input:opt_batchxsample_size --saveEngine=model.engine
```

For more info about `trtexec` use this GitHub [page](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/tree/master/samples/opensource/trtexec).